# unchecked any one checkbox of CellTemplate from the list, I want to uncheck the Header Checkbox

Tags: wpf, checkbox, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection, datagridcolumnheader

I have created a data table which contains 4 columns, 3 are strings and another one is Boolean type. 
i mapped the datatable(xmldatadocument) to the datagridview in wpf. 
so the resulting looks text column and checkbox column in data grid. 
And i added a checkbox header template to the chekbox column header. 
I am able to perform uncheck all checkboxes in column when i\the header checkbox is unchecked. 
I am also able to perform check all checkboxes in column when the header chekcbox is checked.but i am bit troubled in if one of checkbox in that column is unchecked i need to uncheck the header checkbox also.. 
Kindly help me to resolve this.. 
i've added the screenshot, XAML and Code below.

[image: Datagridview]

PS: using WPF datagrid.

```
<dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                <dg:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Check}" Width="50" >
                    <dg:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Name="dtAllChkBx">
                            <CheckBox Name="cbxAll" Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.lblAll}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dg:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>


public static ObservableCollection<Lst> list = new ObservableCollection<Lst>();
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i].Check = true;
    }
}

private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i].Check = false;
    }
}

public class Lst : ObservableCollection<Lst>
{
    public bool Check { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: shouldnt you set the check to true on Checked event and false on Unchecked event? you seem to have done the reverse. Also, is the lst binded to the check box column in the grid?

Comment: @Dzire I corrected it. Yes lst is binded to checkbox column in the grid.

Comment: Have you called property changed on the property binded to the check box column? I tried at my end. I binded the header check box too and changed the property binded to the column. its working

Comment: @Dzire Can u please put the code here. i'll also try on my side.

Comment: @user1328637 Please Implement `INotifypropertyChanged` in your class `Lst` . Also read something on `MVVM`. Your Setter in your class `Lst`does not have a `Change notification` `INotifyPropertyChnaged` will give you an event that you can raise in the setter in your `Property` `Check` . And yes in such cases we usually dont use `Auto property. Plese change to Property with a backing field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the control template for the header

```
<Style x:Key="checkBoxHeaderStyle"
                           TargetType="{x:Type w:DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type w:DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                    <CheckBox 
                                              IsChecked="{Binding  Path = IsSelectAllChecked , Mode = TwoWay}"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
```

Here is the template column applying the style

```
<w:DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="50"
                                              HeaderStyle="{DynamicResource checkBoxHeaderStyle}"
                                              CanUserResize="False">
                        <w:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Name="selectAllCheckBox"
                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                              Margin="1,0,0,0"                                                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path = IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </w:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </w:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The is selected property is

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return selected; }
    set { selected = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }
}
```

For the header check box

```
public bool IsSelectAllChecked
        {
            get { return isSelectAllChecked; }
            set
            {
                isSelectAllChecked = value;
                base.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelectAllChecked");
//Call the method which sets the IsSelected property to true of false, based on value
                SetAllCheckBoxesState(value);
            }

    }
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: What if lst is not binded to checkbox column in the grid?? what changes should i make? I've edited my XAML code... plz check.

Comment: Check my XAML and xaml.cs code and then let me know what changes should i make in that.

Comment: u gotta put in sm effort, i hv provided u wid everything.

Comment: i tried everything but it doesn't work :( none of d forum has d solution for this problem. :(

Comment: Hope u hv binded your check box column with Check property n set d mode as twoway, gimme u checkbox column xaml code

Comment: You forgot to add PropertyChangedEventHander on Setter of the property Check, plz do that first

Comment: <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <dg:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Check}" Width="50" >
                        <dg:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:Name="dtAllChkBx">
                                <CheckBox Name="cbxAll" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=EnggAcc, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.lblAll}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" IsEnabled="True"></CheckBox>

Comment: read about INotifyPropertyChange, you need to put d handler for property change in the setter of Check Property.

Comment: i've included PropertyChangedEventHandler It says SetAllCheckBoxesState(value) does't exist... also i think i've prob in binding Checkbox header to check in XAML. where i have to include style in my XAML code above? and can i eliminate isSelectAllChecked property?

Comment: SetAllCheckBoxesState is a custom method. Look at the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` on google. You gotta learn abt binding.

Comment: I can't define the Style property. Check my XAML code... u've used entirely different properties.. i've used DataGridCheckBoxColumn,HeaderTemplate and DataTemplate but u've used DataGridColumnHeader. VS says this type not found.

Comment: I studied about Data Binding and INotifyPropertyChanged, now i'm able to implement all this. thank u. it was helpful.